# How to boot Windows UEFI from Debian legacy Grub with two SSD drives?

Tags: linux, debian, grub2, dual-boot, grub-legacy

I am using Debian 12, and I am trying to add a new line in the grub menu.

This PC has two SSD drives, the first one has Windows 10 and the second one has Debian 12.

**How can I boot Windows from the Debian Grub?**

The output of `lsblk -f` is:

```
NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL  UUID   FSAVAIL   FSUSE%     MOUNTPOINTS


sdb
├─sda1      ext4   1.0          fec4ac01-0518-472e-a773-398e89e38283  378.9G    14% /
├─sda2
└─sda5      swap   1            1bb8cacf-1774-44b8-9ae7-f939de2cf231                [SWAP]
nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat   FAT32        4643-C150
├─nvme0n1p2
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs                18964D7F964D5DFE
└─nvme0n1p4 ntfs                3480ABF880ABBF2C
```

And the output of `sudo blkid /dev/nvme0n1p3` is:

```
BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="18964D7F964D5DFE" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="548d364e-48f1-499a-8eb3-75e127585773"
```

After that I updated the grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

The file in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Windows 10"{
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 18964D7F964D5DFE
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

But after the reboot, the grub entry appers but there is a message that says that there is not any system...

Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are both systems installed in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives? Windows only boots in UEFI mode with gpt partitioning. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Please add the output of `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo uefi || echo Legacy` to your question.

Comment: Does Windows XP Boot if you select The EFI file from your Firmware's boot menu (F11/Del/etc while booting)?